# Getting comma seperated chars when writing list of strings to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to write the following list of strings

[image]

To a csv file and need the following target format:

```
Image_URLs,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660804/isu8zqke6xoopnemuvvc.jpg,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660805/ldie4gmhaqfhw1df1wls.jpg,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660805/dvbb5kv3dudxhibqpuni.jpg,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660806/inm7ipr8h9ecx1fzcspm.jpg,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660806/b6zxz3qntfzrgvinmv3l.jpg,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660807/a4qsbfeoujfimzvizwha.jpg,
http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660807/lpqenezik6sy1z9xvtzp.jpg,
```

The snippet

```
 with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
                      wr = csv.writer(myfile,lineterminator=',')
                      wr.writerow('Image_URLs')
                      wr.writerows(items)
```

however, generates a comma separated list of chars, instead of strings:

```
I,m,a,g,e,_,U,R,L,s,h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,u,p,l,o,a,d,.,w,i,k,i,m,e,d,i,a,.,o,r,g,/,w,i,k,i,p,e,d,i,a,/,c,o,m,m,o,n,s,/,t,h,u,m,b,/,6,/,6,6,/,P,o,l,a,r,_,B,e,a,r,_,-,_,A,l,a,s,k,a,_,%,2,8,c,r,o,p,p,e,d,%,2,9,.,j,p,g,/,2,2,0,p,x,-,P,o,l,a,r,_,B,e,a,r,_,-,_,A,l,a,s,k,a,_,%,2,8,c,r,o,p,p,e,d,%,2,9,.,j,p,g,h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,p,o,l,a,r,b,e,a,r,s,i,n,t,e,r,n,a,t,i,o,n,a,l,.,o,r,g,/,i,m,g,/,e,d,u,-,c,e,n,t,e,r,-,
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Consider what each of the following does: 1) `[i for i in 'foobar']` 2) `[i for i in ['foobar']]`

Comment: Ah, writerows iterates through each char? i.e. I need to use 
for item in item:
     wr.writerow([item]) ?

Comment: What @jbch is saying is `strings` are treated like `list`s of chars.  `writerow` and `writerows` both look for iterables, so when you pass a `string` value to the function it's iterating through the `chars` in the `list` of `strings`.  Also, I don't think it's a great idea to use *commas* as a `lineterminator` for *comma* seperated values.

Comment: @user1934212 writerows expects something like a list of lists, you can do as you said or `wr.writerows([item] for item in items)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the comments on the question have explained *why* the issue is occurring. One way to *avoid* it altogether is to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) `to_csv`() to write the list to a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd

# Only included 2 image URLs as an example
items = ['http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660804/isu8zqke6xoopnemuvvc.jpg', 'http://res.cloudinary.com/ddpai9fpa/image/upload/v1516660805/ldie4gmhaqfhw1df1wls.jpg']
items = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Image_Urls'])
items.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is small example that can help

```
l = ["A","B","C"]
data = ',\n'.join(l)
f= open("file_name" , "w+")
f.write(data)
f.close()
```